# XTEXT: Avoiding grammar match when used as a parameter

Tags: parsing, xtext

I'm still new to Xtext, so my apologies if this is a simple question.

I have a custom scripting language, that I am attempting to use XTEXT for syntax checking only.  The language has one command per line, and has the format:

```
COMMAND:PARAMETERS
```

I have run into an issue when a parameter for a command is also a command keyword.  The relevant part of the grammar file:

```
Model:
    (commands += AbstractCommand)*
;

AbstractCommand:
    Command1 | Command2
;

Command1:
    command = 'command1' ':' value = Parameter
;

Command2:
    command = 'command2' ':' value = Parameter
;

Parameter:
    value = QualifiedParameter 
;

QualifiedParameter:
    (ID |  ' ' | INT | '.' | '-' )+
;
```

The problem arises when one of the commands uses another another command as it's parameter.  The rules of the language don't allow an actual 2nd command on the same line.  In this case, it is just plain text that happens to have the same value as a pre-existing command.  For example, assume Command1 and Command2 are expecting a complete sentence as it's parameter.  Some sample valid commands would be:

```
Command1:This is a sentence           
Command2:This is also a sentence
Command1:This sentence has Command2 in it
```

All 3 commands are valid, but the last line will generate an error "missing ":" at " ", because "Command2" has its own rules for parsing.

I've been reading the XTEXT documentation, and it seems like I can use first token set predicates to avoid reading the second token when the first is identified, but I cannot find any examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i get your question. maybe what you are looking for is the following:

```
Model: greetings+=Greeting*;
Greeting: "Hello" name=MyID "!";
MyID: "Hello" | ID;
```

this now allows to parse

```
Hello You!
Hello Hello!
```

Comment: I've tried to clarify the original example.  Hopefully it's more understandable now!

Comment: my example shows the solution for that: ```QualifiedParameter:
    (ID |  ' ' | INT | '.' | '-' | 'command1' | 'command2')+
;```. another point is: your grammar reflects the *per line* thing not at all

Comment: I've just included the relevant parts of the grammar, so the _per line_ part isn't included here (but is in the actual grammar file).  Your solution does indeed work, but in the actual grammar file, there are 30-40 commands.  So I would have to list every single command under the QualifiedParameter data rule.  I was hoping for something where I didn't need to explicitly list each command.

Comment: no since keyword go into the lexer you have to list them in the parser rules